Can't use __VA_ARGS__, Error 'this declaration has no storage class or type specifier'
I wanted to make a macro where I can pass the names of the classes and it will automatically create functions for those classes so they can be exported and dynamically loaded. I'm currently doing this in C++.
My problem now is that whenever I have ‘...’ as an argument, and then want to pass the arguments to another macro using __VA_ARGS_, Visual Studio Code tells me ‘this declaration has no storage class or type specifier’. Where is the error? Or how can it be solved in another way?
#define EXPORT_CLASS(Type) \
extern "C" Type* create##Type() { \
    return new Type(); \
} \
extern "C" void destroy##Type(Type* instance) { \
    delete instance; \
}

#define EXPAND(x) x

#define EXPORT_CLASSES_IMPL(Type, ...) \
EXPORT_CLASS(Type) \
IF_NOT_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__, EXPORT_CLASSES_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__))

#define EXPORT_CLASSES(...) EXPAND(EXPORT_CLASSES_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__)) //Called Macro

#define IF_NOT_EMPTY(Condition, ...) EXPAND(IF_NOT_EMPTY_IMPL(Condition, __VA_ARGS__))
#define IF_NOT_EMPTY_IMPL(Condition, ...) IF_NOT_EMPTY_##Condition(__VA_ARGS__)
#define IF_NOT_EMPTY_0(...)
#define IF_NOT_EMPTY_1(...) __VA_ARGS_



EXPORT_CLASSES(TestClass1, TestClass2) //Error here


Your use of IF_NOT_EMPTY() makes no sense. It is trying to invoke IF_NOT_EMPTY_##Condition(), which requires Condition to be either 0 or 1, but it is actually a list of class names instead, so ends up trying to invoke IF_NOT_EMPTY_TestClass2() instead.

Your EXPORT_CLASSES_IMPL is recursive. Unlike in template metaprogramming, I don't think there is a way to define a recursive macro.

This is one of those things where I think it is a rabbit hole of no return; your sanity will suffer less if you just write the C functions by hand.

foreach-macro-on-macros-arguments might interest you
